# react-native updating user location

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to use mapview marker for show direction/route between user location and destination in react-native and a json service that gave the route as points.
now i want when user moves and her location changes, something like OnCoordinateChange for marker coordinate, call a function so i can send real-time start-point location to the router service and get new direction based on new location.

How can i do this?

here is some parts of my code:

(don't pay attention to that piece of #$%@ code between two comment blocks!)

```
      componentDidMount() {
        //User Location
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
          fetch('https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/foot-walking?api_key='+ OsmDirectionApiKet +'&start='+position.coords.longitude+','+position.coords.latitude+'&end={}')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {

/*********
Began some of code that just me and god can understand why and has nothing effect on question!!! 
**********/
            var PolylineGetCoordinates = responseJson.features[0].geometry.coordinates;       
            var PolylineFinalCoordinates = [];
            for(i=0;i<PolylineGetCoordinates.length;i++){
                var obj = {};
                obj.longitude = PolylineGetCoordinates[i][0];
                obj.latitude = PolylineGetCoordinates[i][1];
                PolylineFinalCoordinates.push(obj);
            }

/*********
 End some of $%#@ code!!! 
*********/

this.setState({ 
              PolylineCoordinates :PolylineFinalCoordinates
            });
})
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
          },
          error => {
            this.setState({
              error: 'error'
            });
          }
        );
    }

//-------------------


<Polyline coordinates={PolylineCoordinates} />
```

Answer (score 0):

well found a {SIMPLE} solution!
just moved the codes in componentDidMount() in another function, and changed the codes in componentDidMount to:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getCurrentLocation;
    setInterval(this.getCurrentLocation, 500);
}
```

and added this line to constructor:

```
this.getCurrentLocation = this.getCurrentLocation.bind(this);
```